# DirectoryInfo GetFiles() with more than 8k files

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I'm working on a project and previously blog articles were a text file in a folder. Now we want to store the article content in our SQL Server 2008 server's database.

Right now I'm just trying to get the file name, not inserting any records. Right now it takes more than 15 minutes to finish. This is a Windows Form.

Here's what I have now:

```
private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"P:\op\articles");

    foreach (var currFile in dirInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(currFile.FullName))
        {
            OutputTextBox.Text += currFile.FullName + "\r\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can do something where it only grabs say 1k articles to process and then delete? Is there a more efficient way to make this work faster?

Comment: Is it possible not to put 8k files in one directory?  Perhaps you can make a bunch of sub directories with fewer files in each?

Comment: Why do you initialize a StreamReader for each file? Just curious.

Comment: You could use IEnumerable<T> to take Chunks of the 8000 at a time, so you can process 100 at a time (or any other value).

Comment: @SimonWilson I copied that example. Originally the using state also grabbed all the articles content. I'll try it out to see if it works. Also ashlar64, I can't believe I didn't think about that. Dur.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has told you not to append to a string that way (especially a UI control that will call `Paint()` everytime to append the value.  That is most likely it's slow.  instead append to a `StringBuilder` then apply the `StringBuilder.ToString()` to the textbox.  You can easily test it by commenting out the `Text +=` line and see how fast the method takes.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, that's a very good point.

Comment: @SimonWilson There is a VERY high chance the compiler will optimize the streamreader outside the foreach loop, the [compiler team and JIT are extremely smart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn904673.aspx)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll want to look at `Directory.EnumerateFiles`.  I believe that will enumerate the collection lazily, returning them more efficiently for large sets of files and allowing you to control iteration.

See: [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You beat me to it, interestingly enough the MSDN [GetFiles()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss(v=vs.110).aspx) docs recommend EnumerateFiles for large sets too.

Comment: Nice - This answer works well for what the OP was asking.  Especially for a large initial data-set.  By doing this you can process each element as they are brought into memory as opposed to building the collection, and having to wait.

@SimonWilson The docs are nice sometimes, right :P